# Redirecting audio through RPi

Tags: audio

I have an RPi with minimal Raspbian that's connected to a
speaker, and have set up the sshd.  How can I redirect all audio
from my main machine, which runs Arch Linux, through the RPi to
the speaker?

Comment: What is the main machine? What is the audio source there? Does it stream audio into your local network? Does it use multicast?

Comment: Apple AirPlay comes into my mind. I think you can install a pulseaudio AirPlay sink on your main machine and `shairport-sync` on your Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Bluetooth would also be a solution in close proximity. But then - why wasting a Raspberry Pi if you can get a Bluetooth receiver for as low as $2 from china.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure Raspberry Pi as an audio streaming server and the Arch Linux as an audio streaming client. In this case, both Raspberry Pi and the Arch Linux have to be joined to a local area network.

By [this link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#PulseAudio_over_network), you can do it over TCP to a server running the PulseAudio daemon. Follow procedure up to "Zeroconf (Avahi) publishing".